# ajax call issue in server side processing of datatables

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable, server-side

I am working on server side processing of datatables. 
But I am facing an ajax error which I will explain later. First , here is my code :

**Table**

```
<table id="call_analysis_basic_table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead style="background-color:#4d7496;color:#fff;" id="table_head">
        <tr>
            <th> Column 1 </th>
            <th> Column 2 </th>
            <th> Column 3 </th>
            <th> Column 4 </th>
            <th> Column 5 </th>
            <th> Column 6 </th>
            <th> Column 7 </th>
            <th> Column 8 </th>
            <th> Column 9 </th>
            <th> Column 10 </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dataTable = $('#call_analysis_basic_table').DataTable({
    "processing" : true,
    "serverSide" : true,
    "iDisplayLength": 5,
    "order" : [],
    "sAjaxSource" : {
        url : "http://localhost:8050/phpservice/final.php",
        type : "POST"
    }
});
```

When I load the page, this datatable request started and it creates a url ih browser network settings. This is the url generated by this code :

```
http://localhost:8050/webapp/[object%20Object]?sEcho=1&iColumns=10&sColumns=%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=5&mDataProp_0=0&sSearch_0=&bRegex_0=false&bSearchable_0=true&bSortable_0=true&mDataProp_1=1&sSearch_1=&bRegex_1=false&bSearchable_1=true&bSortable_1=true&mDataProp_2=2&sSearch_2=&bRegex_2=false&bSearchable_2=true&bSortable_2=true&mDataProp_3=3&sSearch_3=&bRegex_3=false&bSearchable_3=true&bSortable_3=true&mDataProp_4=4&sSearch_4=&bRegex_4=false&bSearchable_4=true&bSortable_4=true&mDataProp_5=5&sSearch_5=&bRegex_5=false&bSearchable_5=true&bSortable_5=true&mDataProp_6=6&sSearch_6=&bRegex_6=false&bSearchable_6=true&bSortable_6=true&mDataProp_7=7&sSearch_7=&bRegex_7=false&bSearchable_7=true&bSortable_7=true&mDataProp_8=8&sSearch_8=&bRegex_8=false&bSearchable_8=true&bSortable_8=true&mDataProp_9=9&sSearch_9=&bRegex_9=false&bSearchable_9=true&bSortable_9=true&sSearch=&bRegex=false&iSortingCols=0&_=1502908112765
```

This url sending all the parameters to the required page where server side processing is handled. BUT there is an issue with url after `http://localhost:8050/webapp/` . I dont know what is this `[object%20Object]` doinhg in my URL, where I clearly mention the api url `http://localhost:8050/phpservice/final.php` in the call.

I think everything is fine other than this. Hope So !!
I didnt share my php code because there is nothing wrong with php code, the server side working fine

Any idea why this url behave like this and not behaving as expected ??

Comment: The code you provided isn't creating that url. DataTables isn't going to just magically prepend `/webapp/` to it and omit `phpservice/final.php`.

Comment: The [object%20Object] is the string representation of the javascript object that he is passing in instead of the string that datatables is expecting.

Comment: Can you people tell me why its appending the URL ?

Answer (score 1):

sAjaxSource is not an object. Pass just the URL as a string.
If you need to use POST, set sServerMethod: "POST"

Comment: I have tried this already, I used ` "sAjaxSource" : "http://localhost:8050/phpservice/final.php","sServerMethod" : "POST" `BUT it shows the undefined index error on all the parameters sending in tne above URL